# The main function contains calls to exit() and pthread_exit(). How will the effect of these two calls differ when they are executed?

Tags: c, multithreading, exit

I have a thread  function defined as below:
what is the different between exit() and pthread_exit()?

```
result = pthread_create(&consumer_thread, NULL, consumer_routine, &queue);
if (0 != result) {
    fprintf(stderr, "Failed to create consumer thread: %s\n", strerror(result));
    exit(1);
}

result = pthread_join(consumer_thread, &thread_return);
if (0 != result) {
    fprintf(stderr, "Failed to join consumer thread: %s\n", strerror(result));
    pthread_exit(NULL);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `exit` function terminates the process normally, flushing buffers, calling `atexit` handlers, and so on. The `pthread_exit` function terminates the calling thread, terminating the process only if it's the last thread in the process. Otherwise, the other threads in the process can continue to operate.